# feature detectors and descriptors comparison

Tags: local-features

There are several kinds of detectors and descriptors, like `SIFT, SURF, FAST`.
I wonder are they all eligible for real-time applications? Which is the best or better?

And furthermore, is `Harris-Laplacian` dectector still useful when we already have the above three? Is it better than them?

Comment: You can start by having a look at [A comparison of affine region detectors](http://www.robots.ox.ac.uk/~vgg/research/affine/det_eval_files/vibes_ijcv2004.pdf).

Answer (score 1):

I think SURF is better than all , as its clear from its name , Speed Up robust Feature Detector , but its not free to use , its a patent , so you can't use it for your commercial uses , you can only use it for your studies and knowledge purpose , but i think its also depend on your app that algo to use , but surf is better with speed

Comment: What about **Harris-Laplacian**? It's not a good choice for real-time application, right?

Comment: Harris-Laplacian performs best in scale invariance ,i think your right , but i didn't use harris laplacian

Comment: Perform best? Really? Any proof?

Comment: @loganecolss its depend on your use , you can read about it here : `http://www-scf.usc.edu/~boqinggo/Feature.htm` and as i stated above i didn't use it , thats why i didn't describe it in my answer